# https sites monitoring - Javamelody or other ones

Tags: java-melody

I am trying to monitory my web app (Spring) on tomcat by war file. And, I am trying a tool called Javamelody. It looks very good. But, looks that Javamelody cannot monitor https sites?

I cannot find the exact answer for this. So, I am considering if I should find another tool.

Is there any one who knows something about this Javamelody in terms of https site?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

javamelody can monitor https sites as well as http sites.
There is no difference for javamelody between both.